# Update the VCAP SERVICES on Spring boot application startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We have the scenario where we have to update the VCAP_SERVICE.USER_PROVIDED_SERVICE on the startup of our application due to some limited availability of our CF service availability.

Right now we read/update the env variables via System.getenv(). I want to know is there any other way to update the VCAP_SERVICE via Spring annotations? and Is there any better way to achieve this.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    updateVcapService();
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For now there are no easy way through programmatically. Since your code is in the main application, you should have options to Start the application through the pipeline and update the VCAP services (Using cf cli)  before start the app.